# Loading data into JSON Store

Tags: sencha-touch, jsonp

I'm facing here some dificulties concerning the interaction between my application and server. I really hope you can help me. I like to load user information (name, age,...) provided by the JSONP File into a JSON Store. How can i handle this? thank you very much in advance.

The LogIn function looks as follows:

```
onSigninCommand: function(view, username, password) {
   var data1 = username;
   var data2 = password;
   var me = this;
   loginView = me.getLoginView();
   if (username.length === 0 || password.length === 0) {
       loginView.showSignInFailedMessage('keine eingabe');
       return;
   }
   console.log('Username: ' + username + '\n' + 'Password: ' + password);
   Ext.util.JSONP.request({
       url: 'http://127.0.0.1:4712/talentcommunity/getuserinfo',
       headers: {
           'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded ; charset=utf-8'
       },
       method: 'post',
       params: {
           user: data1,
           pw: data2
       },
       callbackKey: 'callback',

       success: function (response) {

  console.log(response);

  var loginResponse = response;

  if (loginResponse.msg == "OK") {

       var jsonResponse = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
       XXX.store.MyJsonPStore.loadData(jsonResponse);
       me.signInSuccess();
  }

  else {
       loginView.showSignInFailedMessage('token null.');
  }
},

failure: function(response) {
    loginView.showSignInFailedMessage('token null.');
}
});
```

The Store is definied as follows:

```
Ext.define('xxx.store.MyJsonPStore', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
   alias: 'store.myStore',

   requires: [
   'xxx.model.user'
   ],

   config: {
      model: 'xxx.model.user',
      storeId: 'myStore',
      proxy: {
         type: 'jsonp',
         url: 'http://127.0.0.1/talentcommunity/getuserinfo',
         autoAppendParams: false,
         reader: {
           type: 'json'
         }
      }
   }
```

The incomming JSONP file has the following structure:

```
{"msg": "OK",
    "user": {
      "token": "xyz",
      "firstName": "Bertha",
      "lastName": "Muster",
      "age": "24",
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to figure this out ?